# Searching functions or text in Eclipse IDE with large code base

Tags: c++, eclipse, search, ide

I am using Eclipse to work on a large directory of source code (.cpp and .h). This directory has over 200000 source code files and is roughly 5GB in size. One of the problems i'm running into is that it takes a very long time to search for a function or class or any text. It takes roughly 20-30 minutes just to do that. Under the "Project" menu item, I tried to run the "C/C++ Index" ==> "Freshen All Files" in order for it to parse the code to optimize searching, but I've always ran into an Out of memory or GC error message. I'm not sure what to do to by-pass this so that I can successfully index everything. Or better yet, does anyone know a better way to search for functions in this code base? I've been using the "File Search" and "C/C++ Search" and both seem to be very slow :( Any tips/recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `eclipse.ini` file try to increase maximum Java heap space. That'll prevent out of memory errors.

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m //1GB, you can increase when that's not enough
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I'll try it out now. Is this using my RAM memory? I have about 8GB. I wonder how much I can use safely.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be in memory. If your JRE is 32bit you cannot set more than 2GB. As far as I know there is no limit for 64bit systems.

Comment: Ahh what if the code base is say 50GB? Would it be impossible to do indexing for this project?

Comment: A codebase of 50 GB? What is it, all the C++ projects in the world that has been ever written? :) Well, it's not impossible but even if you increase the memory it'll take forever to index it.

Comment: Haha. Lol. Ok thanks. I'll try setting it to Xmx4096m since I have 8GB of memory and cross my fingers!